# Is it Possible to Implement an Icon Button within the CustomButtons Prop of React FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The customButtons prop in React FullCalendar only permits specific configurations like text and icon as strings, alongside other predefined props. However, I'm aiming to utilize an icon button for the header button. Is there a way to include a custom icon for this button within the limitations of the customButtons prop in FullCalendar?
    `<FullCalendar // Other props... customButtons={{ settings: { text: "Settings", click: handleSettingsClick, }, }} />`
I attempted to create a custom button within React FullCalendar using the customButtons prop. Specifically, I tried to define a button with an icon by setting the icon property to "fa fa-car" along with other required properties such as text and click. The expectation was to display a custom icon (utilizing the provided Font Awesome icon class) within the button in the FullCalendar header. However, despite providing the "fa fa-car" class for the icon, the button didn't render the custom icon as anticipated.
    `<FullCalendar // Other props... customButtons={{ settings: { text: "Settings", click: handleSettingsClick, icon: <COGICON />, // Need to use React <COGICON /> instead of "fa fa-car" }, }} />`
It seems that the customButtons prop in FullCalendar only accepts Font Awesome icon classes and does not support custom icons or other forms of icon integration beyond the predefined specifications.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwP2U.png)

Hope You could understood my Matter.